# How do I rename a package in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio and either the files were not correct in the first place or I've messed up the import process.

My project's gen folder is showing the package as com.example.something and my src folder is showing the package as com.myname.something as it should. How can I change the name of the package in the gen folder to match that of the src folder?

I think as a result I'm getting R errors and it's driving me mad!

Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project and imported the files manually in the end. No R errors now either. If anyone knows of an easier way please let me know though!

Answer (score 1):

Try to call from menu Build - > Rebuild Project.

Comment: Tried that :( as well as restarting, rebooting etc etc.

Comment: Try to import your project again.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of the gradle plugin (0.4.3) should solve these problem. More information [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108967384991768947849/posts/Me89CcNPB4P)

Make sure to use "com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+" as dependency in your gradle.build file to get always the latest version.